# Allowing only local network connections to a Windows Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying lock down a virtual machine that acts as an app server for a web application. I have a two VM's: One for the app server and another one running the web server. I have to open a ton of ports to allow the web server talk to some wcf services, but I only want to allow those connections from the web server and no one outside of that network. I have to add endpoints in order for the web server to access the wcf services, but this also makes them accesible to the public IP. How can I only allow this traffic on the

Answer (score 2):

For Virtual Machines, the only way of accessing ports from outside the hosted service is by defining input endpoints (with or without load-balancing across a set of machines). In your case, you'd just open, say, 80 and 443, specifically for your web server (e.g. not load-balanced). This is considered a *port-forwarded endpoint* since traffic on these two ports get forwarded directly to your web server. For more clarity around port-forwarded endpoints, I suggest Michael Washam's blog post, [here](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/06/08/understanding-windows-azure-virtual-machines/).

At this point, you'd open various other ports on your app server (through its firewall config), and now your web server can talk to the app server, yet the outside world won't be able to reach the app server. **Note:** I'm assuming you placed your web server and app server in the same hosted service. Otherwise, you'd need to find a different way to connect between web and app servers, such as configuring a Virtual Network.

**EDIT 6/5/2013** You can now enable ACLs on input endpoints, allowing (or blocking) IP ranges. Today ACLs may only be managed through PowerShell, with the June 2013 update. See [this post](http://michaelwasham.com/2013/06/03/windows-azure-powershell-june-2013-update-for-iaas-and-paas/) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Machines that exist on the same virtual network will be able to talk to each other as long as the local firewall has been opened to those ports. This problem was with my configuration in my application and not because of this. I also didn't have the correct ports open. Now it works like a charm.